# Is there any legal action I can take after my company discouraged me from calling 911 after a workplace injury?

Tags: employment, texas, workplace, injury

I fell at work causing me to have 6 compound femur fractures. I begged my boss to call 911 because my leg was broken . They laughed at me saying there's no way it was broken and that I was exaggerating.

A nurse at the  nurse's station said there is nothing wrong with my leg  and advised me to take myself to the hospital or call someone other than 911.

I called a family member who took me to the hospital where it was determined that I had six compound femur fractures and emergency surgery was performed

What legal actions do I have?

Comment: I doubt there is any law but it seems to me that what they did is highly improper.  There may be company policies that were violated.  If so, there may be grounds for a lawsuit.  You may want to talk to an injury lawyer.  Not my favorite type of person but in this case quite appropriate.

Comment: Be prepared to answer why you called a family member instead of 911.

Comment: @IKnowNothing because in the United States, healthcare isn't single-payer. If the 911 call results in an ambulance roll, the beneficary of that call must pay $1000+++ for the ambulance roll, and the collectors will badger you for years and ruin your credit.  Every member of the lower-middle classes knows this.  So the "best practice" is to assess your probability of 'coding' (needing professional resuscitation) enroute, and if low, use family or Uber to get to the ER.

Comment: @Harper - Then be prepared to explain why you begged your boss to call 911 instead of begging your boss to call your emergency contact.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking the wrong question: it is up to you to decide how to deal with your injury. The employer's role, if any, is limited to after-the-fact compensation. In Texas, workman's compensation coverage is not mandatory, so that is a variable affecting the details. If the employer has workman's comp, they are protected from various legal actions against time, but they also don't get a "vote" in compensation, which is provided by the insurance company.

Assuming that the employer is a non-subscriber (as they are called), then the question of employer liability is resolved either by negotiation or lawsuit. You can read a breakdown of the legal essentials [here](https://www.hg.org/legal-articles/texas-work-injury-law-what-you-need-to-know-51023). When you go to court, you would have to prove that the employer was at fault. Let's assume that you've proven that, then the remaining question is whether that loss is reasonably related to the injury that the employer was responsible for.

There are multiple kinds of medical transportation available, ranging from patient self-transportation on the bus to calling 911. The laws regarding 911 calls are a matter of local jurisdiction, but the general rule is that you only call 911 for genuine emergencies. However, there isn't a clear, practical standard that distinguishes between an emergency vs. "something that you need to deal with eventually". Given your description of the injury, I will work on the assumption that this qualifies as a true medical emergency in your town. Now, typically, 911 EMTs make a professional judgment whether you need ordinary ambulance transportation vs. "Medic One" style transportation – this isn't decided by the employer.

The one area where an employer could have a say in the matter is in accessing his personal or work phone, in order to call 911. Your description of the circumstances is not exactly clear: do you have a phone, or access to a phone? You do not have to have employer permission to make an emergency call on your phone.

So to continue looking for ways to make this a problem for the employer, I will assume that you had no access to a phone of your own or any other employee, and the employer refused to let you use his personal phone or company phone to call 911, but would let you use his phone to call home (this is an entirely rhetorical assumption, but I have no evidence that the situation is otherwise). Now the question is whether the employer has a *legal* obligation to provide access to a work or personal phone in order to make an emergency call. Now we have a specific Texas law, [Penal Code §42.062](https://codes.findlaw.com/tx/penal-code/penal-sect-42-062.html) which says in part that it is a crime when one

> knowingly prevents or interferes with another individual's ability to
> place an emergency call or to request assistance, including a request
> for assistance using an electronic communications device, in an
> emergency from a law enforcement agency, medical facility, or other
> agency or entity the primary purpose of which is to provide for the
> safety of individuals

[Here](https://www.dougmurphylaw.com/interference-with-emergency-calls) is a lawyer's talk-through of this law, which does not address to $64,000 question whether the law creates a "duty to assist" rather than a "duty to not interfere". The answer is tied to the basic lawsuit question of whether the employer is at fault. Under the common law, if a party has created a harmful situation, they have a duty to assist in mitigating that situation.

So if you were horsing around on the job and you're at fault for the injury, then the employer is not liable and you have to shoulder the burden for treatment. If they are at fault, they also have to assist you in seeking emergency medical treatment. I doubt that the courts would find it to be a *crime* to refuse to call 911, but the employer could be civilly liable.

Comment: How about if no one is fault? Sometimes accidents are just accidents with no negligence from either side.

Comment: That's impossible. Instead, both parties could be deemed *equally* at fault. Texas follows the ‘modified joint and several liability’ regime, so the defendant might be held 50% liable, or 10%, or even completely not a fault, it just depends on the facts.

Comment: You start the 911 discussion by disclaiming it's only for genuine emergencies. That seems *disturbingly* tone-deaf to OP's problem, **who absolutely, positively had a 911-importance emergency** and *whose entire issue was idiots denying and suppressing that.* OP has had his concerns minimized/suppressed *far too much already* for your "Bad choice of words?" "deliberate insinuations?" piling on too.  If you want to challenge OP's claims, say directly and with courage.

Comment: "I doubt that the courts would find it to be a crime to refuse to call 911" I'm not familiar with US law, but isn't there a duty to rescue? If it is defined in the Texan legislation didn't the employer fail on that?